# User management & authentication (Free + Self-hosted)

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, authentication, user-management

I'm searching for a headless, **free**, **self-hosted** option to do user management & authentication for multiple apps in my technology stack.

For example, I have a website, a mobile application and a desktop software; written in different languages, doing different things. I want to have a central user base so users don't need to re-signup for each of these. Also, I want the user-management/authentication/authorization to work on its own, so I can change other things in the technology stack (CMS, backend, frontend, ...) without worrying too much.

###### What I want form it:

- Login, Sign Up, Forget Password flows
- Social Logins
- Email, SMS verification (I already have the SMS sending tool. I want to connect it to auth so users can receive a code and use it as the password or for verification)
- **Easy Installation**: Something like WordPress; so I only need to upload some files and do some configurations.
- Secure API routes and roles: Users should have access to specific content only if they have the needed permission. For *example,* only users with Level 2 can see blog posts.
- **Playing well with headless WordPress**: Most of my content is coming from a headless WordPress, through GraphQL. I want to somehow connect it to auth so I can have authorized API calls.

###### Options I found:

I of course searched a lot before asking here. Here are the options I found + why I didn't/couldn't install them:

- **Ory (Ecosystem)**: The best thing I found, but, the installation is complex and my Node.js host doesn't seem to give me full permissions to install it using bash. (*Any help is appreciated regarding installing Ory without docker or bash*)
- **Keycloak**: it uses Java.
- **UserFrosting**: I didn't understand if it gives me APIs to use or comes with a pre-built frontend.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for over 10 years, and haven't found one. My brother ended up writing an app for his work (using Laravel) to do most of this stuff, but right now they won't let him open-source it.

Comment: @MosheKatz Yeah... I know how it feels to look for something for over 10 years... And congrats to your brother!

Comment: I'm currently looking to NextAuth.js and SuperTokens and trying to make one of them work... almost all of the apps in my stack are using Next.js & for others that don't, I'm thinking about creating some sort of redirection/central-login-center. I really have no idea how should I make this system up-and-running 

Comment: You can try Casdoor. It's open source, uses Go + React, has a good-looking web UI, has Swagger docs for API. https://casdoor.org/ , it also supports WordPress via plugin: https://github.com/casdoor/wordpress-casdoor-plugin